# Depending on Babel language setting, I get BibLaTeX error `Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.`

Tags: biblatex, biber, babel, languages

I reduced the problem to the following minimal working example (MWE):

```
\begin{filecontents}{library.bib}
  @misc {test1,
    author = {Author},
    note = {{This note is "bad"}},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
%\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{library.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{test1}
\printbibliography[]
\end{document}
```

The code above works fine. However, if I change the main language with `\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}` I get the following error:

> ```
> ! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
> ```

- Ideally, I'm looking for a solution which doesn't include changing the `.bib` files, because they're external and I don't have control over them. Even though the problem seems to be with `"` and `}` inside the `.bib` file. (I realized that `note = {This note is "bad"}` or `note = {{This note is bad}}` or `note = {{This note is "bad".}}` seem to work with both languages. But `note = {{This note is "bad"}}` isn't malformed, or is it? It *should* work, right?)
- So, maybe I can just set the main language for the `.bib` resource back to `english` as a workaround?

Thanks for any ideas :-)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: I am just welcoming. You did not do anything wrong, yet ;-)

Comment: Put the `filecontents` environment before `\documentclass`

Comment: Incidentally this is the same problem as the recent https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/405610/35864. You should not use `"` for quotation mark, use `csquotes` and its `\enquote{foo}` or ``foo''.

Comment: I assume it pops up from time to time. The `"` thing is probably mentioned in any good introduction to TeX, so many people know it.

Comment: @emmi474. Yes, it's a frequent problem. See the babel docs, sec. «Shorthands».

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example reproduces the issue

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
{"bad"}
\end{document}
```

When `ngerman` is active, `"` is a shorthand character whose action depends on what follows it. For instance `"a` is translated into `\"a` for the umlaut and `"|` sets a morpheme boundary for breaking ligatures. What should never follow `"` is `}` and your `.bbl` file will contain

```
\field{note}{{This note is "bad"}}
```

Removing the unneeded braces does not solve the issue. Use proper quoting

```
note={This note is ``bad''}
```

or, better, use [`csquotes`](https://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) facilities:

```
note={This note is \enquote{bad}}
```

Comment: @emmi474 Yes, `"` should never be used in LaTeX for quotes.

Comment: @emmi474 In general you will need `csquotes` for `\enquote`. `biblatex` defines a poor man's version of `\enquote` if `csquotes` is not loaded. You can turn off `csquotes`' language detection if you don't want it.

Answer (score 1):

I should take the time to read some basic introduction to LaTeX to avoid these problems. The error seems to come from bad quoting. Quoting with `"` is generally a bad idea. On https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Quote-marks for example, it says

> Don't use the " for right double quotes: when the babel package is used for some languages (e.g. German), the " is redefined to produce an umlaut accent

and there are some possible alternatives shown, too.