# How to create an alternative to shortcut "= or \hyp{}?

Tags: errors, compiling, hyphenation, compilation-error, hyphenat

After this question answer [How to use the standard - (hyphen) as the \hyp{} command from the hyphenat package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487648/how-to-use-the-standard-hyphen-as-the-hyp-command-from-the-hyphenat-packa), I decided to not use that hack. Then, I am looking for an alternative to that.

On my case, using `"=` is almost as hard as `\hyp{}` because I write latex code on Sublime Text, and I use this package https://github.com/r-stein/sublime-text-latex-smart-quotes which does this:

[image]

i.e., when I press `"` is sends ``` `` ``` and `''` according to where I am on the word: https://github.com/r-stein/sublime-text-latex-smart-quotes/issues/4

The only way to send `"` is by pressing `Ctrl+L`, `L`, `"`, which is as hard as have to type `\hyp{}`.

I love this feature of because I never have to use `"` unless I would like to do `"=`, but I prefer to keep the https://github.com/r-stein/sublime-text-latex-smart-quotes feature and use something else other than `"=`.

Can I bind it to something as handly as `´=` (not `` `= ``)? Or do you suggest something else?

Then, I can use it like this `something´=hyphenated`, instead of `something"=hyphenated`

I tried doing this: `\newcommand{´=}{\hyp{}}` but latex did not liked it:

```
test1.tex: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

## Update 1

I found this question [How to hyphenate a reference that has a lastname with a hyphen?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98873/how-to-hyphenate-a-reference-that-has-a-lastname-with-a-hyphen) suggesting this, but it had no effect:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\defineshorthand{´=}{\hyp{}}

\begin{document}

\section{Show font}

    Tests.

    Encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding.

    Encoding´=encoding´=encoding´=encoding´=encoding´=encoding´=encoding´=encoding´=encoding´=encoding.

    Encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding.

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Update 2

After reading http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf I managed to get this working:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\useshorthands{"}
\defineshorthand{"=}{\hyp{}}

\begin{document}

\section{Show font}

    Tests.

    Encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding.

    Encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding.

    Encoding´=encoding´=encoding´=encoding´=encoding´=encoding´=encoding´=encoding´=encoding´=encoding.

    Encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding.

\end{document}
```

[image]

But when using something like:

```
\useshorthands{´}
\defineshorthand{´=}{\hyp{}}
```

Latex throws this error:

```
Package babel Info: Making  an active character on input line 5.
test1.tex:5: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

Comment: What comes after `newcommand` must be a macro. Hence the error. Have you considered using the package `csquotes` instead of using that plugin?

Comment: I did not have considered that package. I do know why, but I already have that package included on my thesis template, but seems not to be doing anything useful.  Then, I think I will keep using Sublime Text with `` ``thing''``

Comment: I am using it with `\MakeOuterQuote{"}` and I can type all the double quotes without problem. They are automatically matched and replaced with the correct (opening or closing) one. I seldom use single quotes but there is something similar in the document.

Comment: Check page 12 of the babel manual. You need `\useshorthands*` before you define a shorthand.

Comment: I added that and it worked for `"=`, but for ``´=`` latex throws `Missing \begin{document}`

Comment: Try to switch to a different prefix, there are many to choose from.

Comment: you only need `\hyp ` not `\hyp{}` so if `\ ` is on your keyboard, I don't see why the shorthands are easier to type

Comment: I used only `\hyp` in `\defineshorthand{´=}{\hyp}`, but it still says `test1.tex:5: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}`. Typing `\hyp` is a problem because I always using it inside words like this `some\hypthing`, but latex will think `\hypthing` is a command. Then, I have to put `some\hyp{}thing`, which is not nice to be constantly typing.

Comment: `´` is not an ascii char, it is U+B4, which in utf8 is encoded with two bytes (0xC2 0xB4). You can't use it for a shorthand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. <s>I managed to create this shorthand with `!-`, but</s> it is breaking words after `!` alone. For example, `This is! Sparta.` will show as `This is!Sparta.`
2. <s>Then, instead of using `!-`, I think I will be using `$-` if this does not break anything else.</s> This is breaking Latex text editor syntax parsing. They are thinking we are on math mode after using some `word$-thing`.
3. <s>Finally, using `~-` does not break anything because even when using `~` alone, it works as indented</s> It breaks when using `~--~` dashes.
4. Maybe finally, using `~=` does not break anything because even when using `~` alone, it works as indented:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\useshorthands{~}
\defineshorthand{~-}{\hyp{}}

\begin{document}

\section{Show font}

    Tests.

    Encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding.

    Testing~This motherfoer1.

    Testing~ This motherfoer2.

    Encoding~-encoding~-encoding~-encoding~-encoding~-encoding~-encoding~-encoding~-encoding~-encoding.

    Encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding.

\end{document}
```

-->
[image]

---

See also these other question about the problems the `~=` can cause:

1. [Depending on Babel language setting, I get BibLaTeX error `Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405718/depending-on-babel-language-setting-i-get-biblatex-error-argument-of-language)
2. [! Argument of \language@active@arg has an extra }. (I use \includegraphics and russian)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340661/argument-of-languageactivearg-has-an-extra-i-use-includegraphics-and-r)

They are usually fixed by adding an empty group `{}` after the `~` character, i.e., `\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code~{}}` instead of just `\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code~}`

Comment: As has been said in other comments, you need to use a basic ASCII character (ASCII code 0~126) as the prefix. The prefix you want to use simply won't work.